# MYSQL: дублирование ID при запросе SELECT LIMIT

Tags: mysql, select, innodb

Все привет. Столкнулся с непонятный глюком (или отсутствием понимания) в mysql

есть таблица докторов.
Если делать 2 идентичных запроса с разницой только LIMIT X, происходит дублирование строк. Я не понимаю почему.

```
SELECT id FROM 2020_medicine WHERE id_region=1 AND status=1 ORDER BY rate_summ DESC LIMIT 0,12;

SELECT id FROM 2020_medicine WHERE id_region=1 AND status=1 ORDER BY rate_summ DESC LIMIT 12,12;
```

должны выводить id не повторяющиеся вроде как.

но на деле во второй выборке встречаются id из первой выборки, что не должно быть. почему так? что за глюк?

```
id - int AUTO_INCREMENT первичный, 

id_region - int, 

status - tinyint,

rate_summ decimal(4,1),
```

индекс id_region + status

PS. Версия сервера: 10.3.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 , Версия клиента базы данных: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при этом , если я делаю ORDER BY name ASC (сортировка по полю varchar) - все работает как надо, выводит без повторов.

может я как то не правильно понимаю в сортировке по rate_summ , которая decimal(4,1) ? задача была записать число с десятичной (одна цифра после запятой)

UPDATE: колонка rate_summ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы бы еще колонку rate_summ показали, может там одинаковые значения и order by не знает в каком порядке между собой эти строки выдавать. попробуйте добавить в order by еще и id

Comment: да, там одинаковые значения.

Comment: @Mike, добавил в пост вывод rate_summ. Первый раз с таким в mysql сталкиваюсь, всегда думал что LIMIT X не выводит повторов. т.е. добавить сортировку по ID еще в ORDER BY ? UPDATE: решил проблему добавлением id в сортировку. как то через одно место это

Comment: limit тут вообще не причем. order by не гарантирует порядок строк с повторяющимися значениями. А в вашем случае из за limit видимо выбирается какой то другой план выполнения и порядок нарушается. Конечно добавить id в ордер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

т.к. rate_summ повторяются, нужно добавить сортировку еще по ID в ORDER BY